# JQuery how to select the chosen <option> from a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was wondering how to select only the chosen  element of the same class nested within my  tag in my HTML:

```
<li>
  <select class="country"></select>
</li>
```

If I use the `val()` function it returns only the first element, whereas if I use the `text()` function it returns all the collection hence losing what the user chose.

I need then to compare the data against another collection of data:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "../project1/php/countries.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    if (res) {
      let result = res.map((country) => {
        return country;
      })

      // creates a selector for each country in navbar
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        let option = $("<option></option>", result[i].name).text(`${result[i].name}`).addClass("optionResult");
        $(".country").append(option);

      }
      // Once selectors are created, we can mark the borders when selector is clicked

      $('.optionResult').on('click', function() {
        let selectedCountry = $('.optionResutl').$(this).val();
        
        /// If select val() keeps returning Andorra
        console.log(selectedCountry, 'selected country var'); //seems to be fetching the selected country

        $.ajax({
          url: './countryBorders.geo.json',
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(borders) {
            console.log(borders);

            /// Loop through the borders and check if the selected country is selected
            /// Does not return the chosen country

            let input = [];
            borders.features.forEach((border) => {
              //Debug
              console.log('name in borders', border.properties.name);
              console.log('name in selectors', selectedCountry);

              // Nested forEach ?
              /*  if (border.properties.name == ) {
                    input.push(border);
                }; */
            })

            L.geoJSON(input, {
              style: function(feature) {
                return {
                  color: feature.properties.color
                };
              }
            }).bindPopup(function(layer) {
              return layer.feature.properties.description;
            }).addTo(map);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
  }
});
```

I tried to use the $(this) selector but it throws an error and have not found another way around this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value of a `select` you can simply retrieve its `val()`. Note that this is the value of the `select`, which should be retrieved within the `change` event, not the `click` or `value` of the child `option`.

```js
const $countrySelect = $('.country');

// delegated event handler for selecting a country:
$countrySelect.on('change', function() {
  let selectedCountry = $(this).val();

  // send your AJAX request to get borders...
});

// populate country list via AJAX:
$.ajax({
  url: "../project1/php/countries.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    if (!res)
      return; // handle error, I assume?

    const optionsHtml = res.map(country => `<option value="${country}">${country}</option>`);
    $countrySelect.html(optionsHtml);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
  }
});
```